# Dataset for English word trigrams

Tags: data-request, language, english

Does anyone know where to find such a dataset? There is Google's [Ngram viewer](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) but it is too big to be useful. I'm looking for something smaller. Perhaps with only the 100k most common English words and with most punctuation stripped.